# In The $\{0,1\}$ Space, Every Set Is An Open Set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Our lecture wrote the following comment under the subject of metric spaces:

"In the space {0,1}, every set is an open set"

a. is it correct? (maybe I wrote the wrong set)

b. how can you prove it? we need to show that for every metric we define on the set, both $0$ and $1$ can be contained in an open ball with the metric we defined?

Comment: Hint. A metric on that two element set is determined by a single positive number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** You know that $d(0,0)=d(1,1)=0$ and $d(0,1)=d(1,0)=a>0$.

Pick some $0 < r<a$. What is $B_r(0)$? What about $B_r(1)$?

Answer (score 2):

$X =\{ 0 ,1 \}$ is an example of a discrete space. For every metric you define on the set, because the finite amount of elements, for every point $a\in X$ there will be a minimum distance between $a$ and the rest of the points in the set (let's call it $d_{min}$).

Now, What is the ball with radius $\frac{d_{min}}{2}$? $a$ itself, meaning that every set containing $a$, has an open ball with non-zero radius that is completely in the set (because the ball is $a$ itself).

Answer (score 2):

On a metric space, every singleton is closed. But finite unions of closed sets are closed. Since the space is finite, every subset is then closed. It follows that every subset is also open.

Answer (score 0):

"In the space {0,1}, every set is an open set"

Actually, "the space {0, 1}" makes no sense because, in order to have a "space" you have to have a given topology.  Did you intend to restrict this to metric topologies?  You didn't actually say that in the question itself although you later mentioned a metric.

There are only two possible topologies on a set with two members: {$\phi$, {0, 1}} and {$\phi$, {0}, {1}, {0, 1}}.

In the first, which is not a metric topology, it clearly is clearly **not** true that "every set is open" but in the second, it is. The second is a metrizable space with metric d(0, 0)= d(1, 1)= 0, d(0, 1)= 1 (or any positive number)

Comment: There's another possibility: $\{ \varnothing, \{0\}, \{0,1\} \}$, which is the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space). But of course, it's not related to a metric.